# Android Imaging

Tags: android

I saw your name on web as an android specialist and am looking for some guidance which cannot be taken from android developer lists.
I am developing an application based on android.It needs to send multiple images to the server.

I can send multiple emails each having a single image attachment.Can we send multiple images in a single email attachment?
i.e(as a zip file or attaching many images)

or

Is there a way to append all images to a single image and send a single email with 1 image attachment?

or

Any other way to send multiple images ??

Comment: I can't believe you saw my name on the web as an Android specialist... that's so flattering!

Answer (score 2):

> Can we send multiple images in a
>   single email attachment? i.e(as a zip
>   file or attaching many images)

Sure, if you create the ZIP file.

> Is there a way to append all images to
>   a single image and send a single email
>   with 1 image attachment?

Sure, if you find an image processing JAR that works on Android, will not take excessively long to stitch together your pictures, and has a license that you are amenable to. In other words, use the ZIP file.

> Any other way to send multiple images
>   ??

Send multiple emails. Or, find yourself an SMTP JAR and send the emails that way. Or, upload the pictures to a Web service, and have it send the emails.

Comment: Couldn't you use Android's image manipulation functions for stitching them together?

Comment: Possibly. Haven't played with them, don't know whether they support the OP's desired formats, etc. The bigger problem would then be unstitching them on the other end. Unless the goal explicitly is having the pictures be stitched together, you're better served leaving them as separate files.